AVD fail to start: invalid opcode in libcrypto.so
Windows 11 Pro (i7-8700 32GbRam) fresh install, fully updated
Try to start some AVDs of different versions but with the same kernel panic on kernel messages log:
[    7.423555] init: Skipped setting INIT_AVB_VERSION (not in recovery mode)
[2024-05-26 13:33:18.6] 
[    7.520221] traps: init[1] trap invalid opcode ip:f77e03e5 sp:ffe8ff20 error:0 in libcrypto.so[f7714000+dc000]
[2024-05-26 13:33:18.6] 
[    7.522543] libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xf77e03e5 in tid 1 (init), pid 1 (init)
[2024-05-26 13:33:18.6] 
[    7.528853] init (118) used greatest stack depth: 14424 bytes left
[2024-05-26 13:33:18.6] 
[    7.529973] traps: init[1] trap invalid opcode ip:f77e03e5 sp:ffe8ff20 error:0 in libcrypto.so[f7714000+dc000]
[2024-05-26 13:33:18.6] 
[    7.531774] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004
[2024-05-26 13:33:18.7] 
[    7.532995] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Tainted: G           O      5.4.86-android11-2-00006-gae78026f427c-ab7595864 #1
[2024-05-26 13:33:18.7] 
[    7.534580] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.11.1-0-g0551a4be2c-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
[2024-05-26 13:33:18.7] 
[    7.536368] Call Trace:

Hyper-V enabled, tried to disable gpu, hw accelerator, different api versions, etc... tried also to setup emulator by installing Android Studio, Visual Studio (MAUI) o manually, with same result.
p.s. everything works fine prior to formatting the system.
Any advice on whats going on?
Thanks
DPZ

Solved: Advanced Encryption Standard-New Instructions(AES-NI) was not enabled in BIOS (after an upgrade).
